# Can we declare dependency to projects packaged in POM ( Maven )

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

In maven we can declare dependency to projects packaged in war or jar.
Can we declare dependency to Pom packaged project ?
if not, is there an alternative to do that

Comment: You can declare dependencies in Pom Packaged project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can declare a dependency to another pom  packaged project. Try included something like below  inside your dependencies tag.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>yourgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>yourartifact</artifactId>
    <version>artifact version</version>
    <scope>scope</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, we can.

As @obama had already correctly mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this does only make sense if you define the dependencies in `dependencyManagement` and use them with `<scope>import</scope>` [so called BOM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies)